# Java reading files

Tags: java

I am trying to learn file reading and writing, but I tried it with BufferedReader, and Scanner, it will always show the exception message. I followed the steps in the book tho. Not sure what went wrong.

```
package fileIO;

import java.io.*;

import java.util.*;

public class files {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String line = "";
        BufferedReader br = null;
        try{
            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Shadow.txt"));
            while(br.readLine() != null){
                line += br.readLine();
                System.out.println(line);
            }


        }catch(FileNotFoundException e){
            System.err.println("File not found");
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("Throwing exception");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It would be very useful if you told us what *the exception message* is that it always shows.That means you have to stop throwing away the actual message and show what it contains. Replacing the useful info with a meaningless message is wrong. If you don't want to properly use `Exception e`, then remove the handler for it entirely and don't catch it, and see what the real problem is that's causing it to be thrown.

Answer (score 1):

Change your `while` a little bit:

```
while( (line = br.readLine() ) != null ) {
  System.out.println(line);
}
```

Comment: Correct but it doesn't explain the exception.

Comment: It doesn't work for me tho, I tried that before, but the file is still not found, should I use the pathname instead?

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
import java.io.*;

class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Printer.print("Shadow.txt");
    }
}

public class Printer {
    public static void print(String filename) {
        String line;
        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename))) {
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) System.out.println(line);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            System.out.close();
        }
    }
}
```

I upgraded you to a try-with-resources, and fixed your while-loop. Hopefully it's also an example of how to write more modular code.

Comment: This one is working, I don't know why it does not work with a try-catch block